# MS03-026 RPC DCOM Exploit not working on metasploit

Tags: metasploit, vulnerability, windows-xp

I'm trying to exploit Windowx XP SP2 through MS03-026 Microsoft RPC DCOM Interface Overflow vulnerability on msfconsole. When execute "exploit" but it is not working. What could be reason?
The one said on -
http://www.rapid7.in/db/modules/exploit/windows/dcerpc/ms03_026_dcom

Access Mode : VMware Workstation 9
Host OS : Windows 8.1
Guest OS : Windows XP Service Pack 2
Network type : Host-only

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.  You maybe using a decade old exploit,  maybe you are patched?  Which one of the dozen or so dcom exploits are you attempting to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the Windows XP you are using, is patched for that vulnerability.

Comment: This is not an answer but more of a comment. With the question so broad, you could not conclusively state that Windows XP is patched forany vulnerability considering there are a variety of dcom exploits for Windows XP.

Comment: I understand. But I didn't have enough reputations to comment. I'm a newbie here. :(

Comment: Actually there is enough information. Service Pack 2 was released in 2004 with the MS03-026 patch included.

Also if you look at the code for the Metasploit module you can see which versions of Windows it can target: => Windows NT 4.0 SP6a, Windows 2000, Windows XP SP0/SP1, Windows 2003, Windows NT 4.0 SP5, Windows NT 4.0 SP3/4